# Append li before an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I would like to use jQuery to append a `li` before an element like below:
At first it is:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p> content </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And after should be :

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p> content </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

For my code it happens this:

```
<li></li>
<div>
    <div>
        <p> content </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is not what I want. I am looking for the second example. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What about div tags? You have to add them too?

Comment: and what is the jquery code you using?

Comment: What u have tried in javascript/jquery?

Comment: If you need to wrap `DIV` with `LI` after page loads, html is invalid to start with since `DIV` can't be a direct child of `UL` or `OL` and javascript isn't going to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) can do that:

```
$("selector for your div").wrap("<li>");
```

**However**, I can't immediately imagine a structure where that's valid. Either the `div` is invalid (because you can't have a `div` as a direct child of a [`ul`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), [`ol`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element), or [`menu`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element)), or once you put the `li` in, *it's* invalid (because [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) **must** be the direct child of a `ul`, `ol`, or `menu`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 <div id="here" >
         <div>
         <p> content </p>
         </div>
   </div>


$('#here').wrap('<li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

don't try append..

Create independent LI and wrap it over the div instead.

```
<div id="myDiv" >
         <div>
         <p> content </p>
         </div>
   </div>


$('#myDiv').wrap('<li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be like this:

```
$('p:contains(content)').parent().parent().wrap('<li>');
```